# IBM Process Center user roles for deploy only

Tags: websphere, ibm-bpm

I'm new in IBM Process Center (BAW 19.0.0.3).
We have DEV env (Process Center PC) and PROD env (Process Server PS). PS will be connected to the PC for fast deploy snapshots from DEV to PROD.

I'm trying to understand how to create two users using external LDAP (as example): 1st user like developer only (has no grants for deploy snapshot to PROD env) and the 2nd user with deploy only grants (like Project Deployer user).

I know about two adminstrave groups (tw_admins and tw_authors), but I can't understood how it works. Users in tw_authors can delpoy snapshots to Process Server. I have no idea how to create this user with deploy only grants.

Thanks